# Sitecore 9 Installation error "Failed to start service 'Sitecore xConnect Search Indexer"

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 in my Windows 10 box. At first attempt, it was failed with this exception.

> Failed to start service 'Sitecore xConnect Search Indexer'

I got the one answer for this issue [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9932/failed-to-start-service-sitecore-xconnect-search-indexer-when-installing-sitecor). But it is related to `LicenseException` in EventLog. But i am having different exception in my EventLog as follows.

> The Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - sc9.xconnect-IndexWorker
>   service terminated with the following error:  An exception occurred in
>   the service when handling the control request.

Apart from it, i can also see few Application Level EventLog exceptions listed below..

> The Open Procedure for service ".NETFramework" in DLL
>   "C:\windows\system32\mscoree.dll" failed. Performance data for this
>   service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the
>   Data section contains the error code.
>
> The Open Procedure for service "BITS" in DLL
>   "C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for this
>   service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the
>   Data section contains the error code.
>
> The Open Procedure for service "Lsa" in DLL
>   "C:\Windows\System32\Secur32.dll" failed. Performance data for this
>   service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the
>   Data section contains the error code.
>
> Unable to open the Server service performance object. The first four
>   bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.
>
> The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL
>   "C:\windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for
>   this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of
>   the Data section contains the error code.

Comment: just to make sure: you have all prerequisites installed, solr running via https and service was created but cannot start? can you open xConnect url in browser (you should see just a time string)?

Comment: Yes, all are done. When trying to access xConnect url in browser, it gives me error at IIS level.

Comment: Looks like an issue with performance counters.  See if any of these help: http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/306-resolved-the-open-procedure-for-service-bits-in-dll-c-windows-system32-bitsperf-dll-failed-performance-data-for-this-service-will-not-be-available-the-first-four-bytes-dword-of-the-data-section-contains-the-error-code.html

Comment: Do you see any errors in xConnect Indexer log file?

Comment: Just veirfy your license is not expired. In my case i got this error due to my sitecore license was expired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently got the same error and got it fixed by performing the below steps:

1. Make sure that my license support Sitecore xConnect. Please contact your Sitecore regional officer to ask about if your license is eligible for xConnect. Normally, they would need to regenerate a new one. If this license was used on Sitecore 8, then you need to ask for a new one for Sitecore 9.
2. Make sure solr is running on https and the solr service is on.
3. Once the above is confirmed, I deleted everything and started from scratch. Follow the link you posted to know what to remove.

You can read my post on [how to get Sitecore 9 with xConnect](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2018/02/10/sitecore-9-using-installation-framework/). This is what I have used to setup the Sitecore instance.

Answer (score 2):

Once I got the same error while setting up Sitecore 9.0.1 and the cause was a wrong license file in this path.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data
```

Even though you have the right license.xml file in your

```
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.xconnect\App_data\
```

path, you can still get this error message. So my solution was replacing the license.xml file in previous path, while install.ps1 file working.