# How to check whether my license file supports Sitecore 9 and xConnect

Tags: xconnect, licensing

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 on my Windows 10 machine. I came across many issues during installation. Finally i stuck at almost last step where installation script tried to start xConnect service asked [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10151/sitecore-9-installation-error-failed-to-start-service-sitecore-xconnect-search).

Hishaam Namooya suggested [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10151/sitecore-9-installation-error-failed-to-start-service-sitecore-xconnect-search/10197#10197) to check the license file whether it supports xConnect or not. I raised a new license request at Sitecore Partner Resources Portal as we are Sitecore Partners. I got a new license file and tried again for installation but got same exception again.

Now, i really don't know, whether the new license file supports xConnect or not  and i can use this license for Sitecore 9?

Is there any way to check this in provided license xml?

Comment: I answered your question, but the chances are that your license is fine and the problem lies elsewhere. If that is the case, please create a separate question and include the full text of the errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The license required for using xConnect is called `Sitecore.xDB.Base`.

If you have access to a Sitecore instance using that license, open the Launchpad, go to Control Panel and open Installed Licenses. You should see this license in the list.

Or you can just open the license.xml and look for the part that looks like this:

```
<Object xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Sitecore.xDB.Base">
  <module xmlns="">
    <idref>...some id here...</idref>
    <name>Sitecore.xDB.Base</name>
    <count>1</count>
    <expiration>...some date here...</expiration>
    <version>8</version>
    <comment />
    <licenseagreement>?</licenseagreement>
  </module>
</Object>
```