# Sitecore 9 Installation :: Could not find Solr instance

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

I'm following given post for Sitecore 9 Set up on local machine
[Sitecore 9 set up](https://sitecoresolver.blogspot.in/2017/11/sitecore-xp-90-local-instance-setup.html)

Got below error on install.ps1 execution even I'm able to browse the Solr URL( https://localhost:8985/solr/ ) successfully

[image]

Where should I look at further now. Any suggestion

OS: Windows 8.1
IIS: 8.5
PowerShell 5.1
Solr: 6.6.2

I tried work around from below post but no luck

[SolR issue](https://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2018/01/)

Comment: Please include this error stack trace as regular text (not image), or the question has no value for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try upgrading your Sitecore Install Framework to version 1.2+ and SIF Fundamentals to 1.1+.  I had this same issue when I was running 1.0 of both SIF and Fundamentals.  My Solr instance was definitely present because I could navigate to it, but what I found was happening, is that SIF is restarting the service that runs Solr, but I guess it doesn't restart fast enough.  I noticed the newer versions of SIF and SIF Fundamentals, retries the instance a few more times before it fails, which typically on the 2nd or 3rd try it works correctly.

If you are not sure how to upgrade SIF and SIF Fundamentals, try the following:

1. Open Powershell as an Administrator.
2. Register a connection to MyGet feed

```
Register-PSRepository -Name SitecoreGallery -SourceLocation https://sitecore.myget.org/f/sc-powershell/api/v2
```

3. Then type the following commands to install the latest version of
   each:

```
Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
Update-Module SitecoreFundamentals
```

That should be it.  Now try to re-run Sitecore Install Framework.  You can optionally also do `Install-Module [Name_of_module]`

You can check the version of your module by importing the module by running `Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework` and then running `Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework`.

Comment: In 1.2 we introduced a prerequest check to ensure the solr service was responding before make the actual request to manage cores. Dylan is spot on here with his answer.

Comment: Ok so now I'm trying to update latest SIF and tried to register SitecoreGallery but got error message:
PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : Module Repository 'SitecoreGallery' exists.
so looks like connection is already established

then executed Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework and get below error:
Update-Module : Module 'SitecoreInstallFramework' was not installed by using Install-Module, so it cannot be updated.
I'll try Manual Installation

Comment: Well...It's very strange. I did SIF manual installation and ran Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework -ListAvailable command and as a result I could see SIF 1.2.0 version in power-shell

after this I ran SC9 install.ps1 but getting same error -->

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not find Solr instance: https://localhost:8985/solr

Comment: now I ran Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework in PS and then Get-Module SitecoreInstallFramework this time I'm getting version 1.0.2 looks like manual installation was not proper...might be system reboot required

Comment: Well...I went ahead and uninstall SitecoreInstallFramework/SitecoreFundamentals modules from PS and install again using Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework command so now this problem is solved...but next issue when I executed when I installed .install.ps1

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer -
MySC9Website.xconnect-IndexWorker (MySC9Website.xconnect-IndexWorker)'.

Comment: I found below message in logs:
Required license is missing: Sitecore.xDB.Base
then I verified existing license going through https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/how-to-check-whether-my-license-file-supports-sitecore-9-and-xconnect?rq=1

I do have Sitecore.xDB.Premium so I think SC9 installation should work. Isn't it?

Comment: This is turning into a discussion thread that goes way beyond the scope of the original question. If you need assistance in debugging your Sitecore 9 installation, please come find us on Slack or start a Community Forum discussion thread.

Comment: Sure @MarkCassidy I'll mark this done because I got the solution in context of original question so installing latest SitecoreInstallFramework/SitecoreFundamentals modules worked out


thanks dylan / Kieranties for you response